# How to read a .db file in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a excel file and want to store my excel file into a .db file. I have done that through sqlite. Now, I want to read my .db file through Python which I am unable to do as the code I have used says that the data is empty.

Below is the code:

```
df=pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
db='xyzDB'
conn=sqlite3.connect(db + '.sqlite')
c=conn.cursor()
table_list = [a for a in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'Sheet1'")]
print(tablelist)

#another method

chunksize = 10000
for chunk in pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', chunksize=chunksize):
     chunk.columns = chunk.columns.str.replace(' ', '_') #replacing 
     chunk.to_sql(name='Sheet1', con=conn)

names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], c.description)) #Returns the column names
print(names)
for row in c:
     print(row)
```

Note: have found these two codes from net and didn't understand the code. Would appreciate if you could guide me.

Comment: By the looks of it, you're saving the values from the .xlsx into the .db AFTER you're reading the values of the .db. Can you elaborate on what the expected behavior is?

Comment: I want to first store the excel data into .db file. Then, want python to read the .db file and show me the data in it on Python

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this ...

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sq

# read csv into data frame
df=pd.read_csv('addresses.csv')

sql_data = 'addresses.sqlite'
conn = sq.connect(sql_data)

# write the data frame to the db

df.to_sql('addresses', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
conn.commit()

# read back from the database
print(pd.read_sql('select * from addresses', conn))

conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. it did work. Is it possible to read the db data in Python in a presentable manner as a portion of the data is shown in Python console (looks messy). I want to look at the whole data

Comment: pd.read_sql returns a pandas dataframe :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html
you can access data from it to your hearts content!

Comment: Hey! pd.read_sql does return the dataframe. But when i use the above code with  large excel file size e.g larger than 70 mb size.. it increases the file size. Need help